# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField not displaying correct Choice names

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am attempting to create a Multiple Choice Field from a view on my postgres db, however the webpage is displaying incorrectly. Specifically, while it provides the correct number of selections it does not name them by the "check_name" field, instead it names every selection 'Check object'. Here's my code:

**models.py**

```
class Check(models.Model):
    pkey = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cif = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    check_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'precheck_check'
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProcessFileForm(forms.Form):
    checks_to_run = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = Check.objects.all(),
        to_field_name = "check_name",
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        )
```

**views.py**

```
def successful_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProcessFileForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'precheck/checks_successful.html')
    else:
        form = ProcessFileForm()
    return render(request, 'precheck/select_checks.html',{'form':form})
```

Of note, I am pulling the data from a view named 'precheck_check' in the postgres db. It seems to be seeing the view correctly since it is giving me the correct number of choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest fix is to add a [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#str) method to your `Check` model.

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible  # only if you need to support Python 2
class Check(models.Model):
    pkey = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cif = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    check_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'precheck_check'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.check_name
```

If you want to display a different value than result of the `__str__` method, you can subclass [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) and override `label_from_instance`.

```
from django import forms

class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.check_name
```

Then use the field in the form:

```
class ProcessFileForm(forms.Form):
    checks_to_run = forms.MyModelMultipleChoiceField(...)
```

Comment: This worked for me so I accepted the anser, but shouldn't the `to_field_name = "check_name"` have accomplished the same thing?

Comment: No. As the [example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) shows, the `to_field_name` controls the value of the option (which you don't see), not the label which you do see.