# Django form - SelectMultiple changing the visible value

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm a junior dev. Working on the project in Django 1.8, Python 2.7.15.

What do I want to achieve?

I want to change the names of groups 'test_X' to another string (payment title), but not in the database... only in the visible layer of form. (SelectMultiple widget)

In groups I have something like this:

```
Super Group 
Extra Group 
New Group 
test_1 
test_2 
test_3 
Great Group
test_4 
(...)
```

The 'test_x' groups are connected via one to one field to Payments model.

Just look on my code:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    (...)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
    virtual_group = models.OneToOneField(
        Group,
        null=True,
        related_name='virtual_group',
    )

class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = (
             (...), 'group',
        )
        labels = {
            (...),
            'group': u'Choose specific group',
        }
        widgets = {
            'group': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control chosen', 'data-placeholder': 'Select group'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.prepare()

    def prepare(self):
        (...)
        groups = Group.objects.all()

        # here I'm changing names of groups 'test_X' to the tournament title using one to one connection
        list_of_proper_names = [g.name if not 'test' in g.name else g.virtual_group.title for g in groups]

        # in ok I got proper values (this is list of strings -> group names and Payment titles)
        # and here I'm trying to pass only group names and titles

        self.fields['group'].initial = list_of_proper_names
```

but this doesn't work.... I always get REAL group names in the view so I still got "test_1", "test_2" etc.

This is happening even after I changed these names in list comprehension above

I tried also with

```
self.fields['group'].queryset
```

but here I can't pass a list of strings, the only query set so if I pass `Group.objects.all()` again I got the result with "test_1", "test_2"

I don't know how to override the group names "test_X" with the title of Payment. It is still the same id/pk... but I just want to rename it with corresponding (via one to one field virtual_group) payment title.

(I had to use test_X because key must be always unique)

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168925/django-modelmultiplechoicefield-not-displaying-correct-choice-names/45169112#45169112) might help. In particular subclassing [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) and overriding `label_from_instance`.

Comment: Yeah just misspell in my text.
In my code I have it the right way.... but it still doesn't work right ;/

Comment: In your edit you say you’ve tried to set `queryset`, but you haven’t used a custom model choice field as I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: Yeah you are right it may help! Thanks! Any idea how to monkeypatch __ str __ method of Group that is in auth.models?